# Different packageRules for release and prelease versions

Tags: semantic-versioning, renovate

Is there a way to configure renovate with packageRules, so that I get a MR with automerge disables for pre-release versions, like v1.0.0-alpha.1 and MR with automerge enabled for patch versions, liken v1.0.0.

I have enabled unstableVersion support in renovate, but I want different behaviors for release/prerelease versions. My current configuration looks like the following, but I am unsure if this works, because the documenation of renovate states that `prerelases` is not a valid value for `matchUpdateTypes`.

```
    {
      "matchDatasources": [
        "git-tags"
      ],
      "matchManagers": [
        "ansible-galaxy"
      ],
      "matchUpdateTypes": [
        "patch"
      ],
      "enabled": true,
      "automerge": true,
      "platformAutomerge": true
    },
    {
      "matchDatasources": [
        "git-tags"
      ],
      "matchManagers": [
        "ansible-galaxy"
      ],
      "matchUpdateTypes": [
        "prerelease"
      ],
      "enabled": true,
      "automerge": false,
      "platformAutomerge": false
    },
```

What I want is that renovate automerges

- v1.0.0 -> v1.0.1
- v1.0.2-alpha.1 -> v1.0.2

but no automerge (only MR) for

- v1.0.0 -> v1.0.1-alpha.1
- v1.0.1-alpha.1 -> v1.0.1-alpha.2

Answer (score 0):

According to https://docs.renovatebot.com/modules/versioning/#regular-expression-versioning, you could set `"ignoreUnstable": true`